# Custom ClassSerializerInterceptor in NestJS to serialize based on user role (express req object)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, interceptor

In NestJS route, I want to serialize reponse based on request (user's role). This means that I need to pass option `groups: []` into `transformToPlain` method in `ClassSerializerInterceptor` so class-transformer can properly return filtered format:

This is original interceptor source: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/serializer/class-serializer.interceptor.ts

I just extended this class and changed `intercept` method to also include `group` option based on request:

```js
export class CustomClassSerializerInterceptor extends ClassSerializerInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // @ts-ignore
    const contextOptions = this.getContextOptions(context);
    const options = {
      ...this.defaultOptions,
      ...contextOptions,
      groups: request.user.roles // Pseudo
    };
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(map((res: PlainLiteralObject | Array<PlainLiteralObject>) => this.serialize(res, options)));
  }
}
```

My entity:

```
export class Content extends BaseDatabaseEntity {
  @Column()
  @Transform((type) => EContentType[type])
  type: EContentType;

  @Expose({ groups: ["MODERATOR", "ADMIN"] })
  @Column({ default: "[]", type: "json" })
  data: TContentDataColumn[];
}
```

Is this proper way to do it? For example `this.getContextOptions` method is private in original source, so I need to do ts-ignore here, to override default intended privacy of class which seems to me as big no-no.

Am I even supposted to transform API response based on user's role, or it is anti-pattern?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `@SerializationOptions()` decorator to [pass extra options](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization#pass-options) based on what route is being triggered. As it seems you need to do this dynamically, you could go so far as to use the `Reflect` namespace and set the metadata each request. The metadata token is `'class_serializer:options'`, so you could do something like

```js
Reflect.defineMetadata(
  'class_serializer:options',
  { groups: req.user.roles },
  Class.prototype,
  'method'
);
```

It's not necessarily pretty, but it could work

Answer (score 2):

##### For NestJS >= 8.0

Yes, **extending** the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` is an adequate way to add more functionality into it.

As *@Baterka* have pointed out, this always worked but triggered compiler warnings.

Since then the source code has been changed so previously ***private*** fields like `defaultOptions` and `getContextOptions` are now ***protected*** instead, meaning they are available to derived classes.

**Here is a working example** that's fully compatible with NestJS version 8.0 or later:

> **roles-serializer.interceptor.ts**

```
import { CallHandler, ClassSerializerInterceptor, ExecutionContext, Injectable, PlainLiteralObject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  
@Injectable()
export class RolesSerializerInterceptor extends ClassSerializerInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    const userRoles  = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user?.roles ?? [];
    const contextOptions = this.getContextOptions(context);
    const options = {
      ...this.defaultOptions,
      ...contextOptions,
      groups: userRoles
    };
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        map((res: PlainLiteralObject | PlainLiteralObject[]) =>
          this.serialize(res, options)
        )
      );
  }
}
```